# Can i have multiple spring mvc project controller with different type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

i'm using to make a spring mvc application, in the pom.xml file i have

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

because the project's based on the version 4 of spring i know that i can use the annotation `@RestController` but the problem i have to use `@Controller` too in another Controller.
any way how could i make mvc controller and Rest controller in same project?

Answer (score 0):

`@RestController` and `@Controller` are not mutually exclusive. You can use both in your project. `@RestController` is just a more specialized version of `@Controller` which is equivalent to having both `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.